# page numbers on the side of the page

Tags: margins, page-numbering

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to have page numbering on the side of the page? I mean on the right side on odd pages and on the left side on even pages.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Another possible solution would include package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That question doesn't address moving the page number to the (vertical) center of the page, it just places it on the outside of the header.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry, I took the false link, I will look for another one

Comment: Probably a MWE for this would be an empty article-document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed up on the solution proposed by alexises, completing the code.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\fancypagestyle{Plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[EC]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node[xshift=3cm,font=\bfseries] (number) at (current page.west) {\Huge[\thepage]};
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
  \fancyfoot[OC]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node[xshift=-3cm,font=\bfseries] (number) at (current page.east) {\Huge[\thepage]};
      \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
}

\fancypagestyle{nonums}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[OC]{}
    \fancyfoot[EC]{}
}

\pagestyle{Plain}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\lipsum[11-15]

\thispagestyle{nonums}

\lipsum[16-18]

\end{document}
```

For a page without the page number use `\thispagestyle{nonums}` at an appropriate point in the document.
Screenshot:

[image: Preview of bold page nums at side of page, including page with no number.]

**Later:**

I wanted an approach that did not rely on the `twoside` option. `tikzpagenodes.sty` makes this possible because the locations of the page numbers are relative to the current *text block*, not the edge of the page.

```
\documentclass{article} %% Use [twoside] if needed
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\fancypagestyle{Plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{%
      \ifodd\thepage
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node[xshift=2cm,font=\bfseries] (number) at (current page text area.east) {\Huge[\thepage]};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \else
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node[xshift=-2cm,font=\bfseries] (number) at (current page text area.west) {\Huge[\thepage]};
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \fi
  }%
}

\fancypagestyle{nonums}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{}
}

\pagestyle{Plain}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\lipsum[11-15]

\thispagestyle{nonums}

\lipsum[16-18]

\end{document}
```

Here is the non-`twoside` output:

[image: Non-twoside output]

And here is the `twoside` output:

[image]

Comment: your solutions works very, very well! thank you for helping me. I use \thispagestyle{empty}, because on the pages without page numbers there is no header, too. thank you once more!

Comment: It's a bit rude of you to post a fully fleshed out version of @alexises solution when you haven't up-voted his answer! :) (There's currently one up-vote for his solution and it's mine!)

Comment: Actually, the code, as presented, produced numerous TeX errors: 1) \textbf requires an argument -- \bfseries is the thing to use; 2) The use of math mode `\[...\]` in the Tikz node produced errors; 2) There were two missing ';' characters. I did not want to draw attention to the problems. Will Durant: "To speak ill of others is a dishonest way of praising ourselves. . . let us be above such transparent egotism." I simply presented an approach based on what was essentially a very good idea.

Comment: @Andrew -- You are correct, however, I should have up voted the answer, which I have done. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `TikZ` with `fancyhdr`

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[EC]{%
      \begin{tikz}[overlay]
          \node[font=\textbf,xshift=0.5cm] (number) at (current page.west) {\[~\thepage~\]}
      \end{tikz}
  }%
  \fancyfoot[OC]{%
      \begin{tikz}[overlay]
          \node[font=\textbf,xshift=0.5cm] (number) at (current page.east) {\[~\thepage~\]}
      \end{tikz}
  }%
}
```

Comment: A full document and a screen shot would make this a real answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this using the [background](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package. Stealing from the manual a little, you can get:

[image]

(I could only display an even page next to an odd page...)

The LaTeX for this is fairly easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pages=all,color=black,opacity=1,scale=4,contents={},angle=0,%
            contents={}]{background}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\AddEverypageHook{\ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
  {\backgroundsetup{position={0,-0.15\textheight}, contents={[\thepage]}}}%
  {\backgroundsetup{position={0.34\textwidth,-0.15\textheight}, contents={[\thepage]}}}%
  \BgMaterial%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The placement of the page numbers is a little haphazard and could be improved. I don't really like the format of [x] for the page numbering, but for this I followed the OP. I would prefer something like a greyed -x-. It's also not hard to put the number in a `\fbox` etc.

Finally, I should say that I am cheating a little here because `background` uses `tikz` behind the scenes, so this is similar to the solution that @alexises has already posted.

**Edit**

If you want to drop the page numbers from some pages then you can do it by adding using the following modification and putting `\PageNumberfalse` on the pages where you don't ant numbers (this will only take effect for one page):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pages=all,color=black,opacity=1,scale=4,contents={},angle=0,%
            contents={}]{background}

\newif\ifPageNumber\PageNumbertrue
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifPageNumber%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
        \backgroundsetup{position={0,-0.15\textheight}, contents={[\thepage]}}%
    \else%
        \backgroundsetup{position={0.34\textwidth,-0.15\textheight}, contents={[\thepage]}}%
    \fi
    \BgMaterial%
  \fi\global\PageNumbertrue% by default number all pages
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum\lipsum\PageNumberfalse\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

(For good measure I dropped the use of the `ifthen` package...not sure why I used it before:)

Comment: Andrew, your solution is very good and works well for me. thank you. the only problem is that command \NoBgThispage doesn't work. I need some pages without page number

Comment: @user60291 I've just added a quick hack for manually dropping some of the page numbers.

Comment: Andrew, it works! thank you very much for your help. I'm a beginner :)

Comment: @Zbynek No problem. Glad to help!

Comment: Andrew, another problem. second solution causes that header and footer disappear everywhere :(

Comment: is it possible to add header text to the background? it is different for odd and even pages too

Comment: @Zbynek The easiest way to do both is to add the header material into the fancy header solution proposed by 
alexises.